# Kivy window goes blank after being resized

Tags: python, kivy

I'm still relatively new to Python and Kivy (much more so for Kivy). I'm running Python 3.5 and Kivy 1.9.1 on OS X. I installed Kivy using pip install, and I was never really able to get Kivy to work using the download and putting in my Applications folder like the instructions were asking. Everything seems to work fine, and I've made a few apps; however, I seem to encounter a problem whenever I try to resize the window. The window goes white while I'm resizing it, and then it turns blank/black afterwards. The terminal just says that it reloaded the graphics and the amount of time it took. I was hoping that after I made my apps using Pyinstaller that this would go away, but the problem still persists. Has anyone else encountered this problem? I haven't been able to test this on another computer yet to see if the problem persists. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!(:

Comment: might be related to a "bug" they have Minimize the window, then restore it; the app canvas is white/black until the window is resized or a button/textinput is clicked, or anything else that triggers a canvas update. issue #2572  but happens to me when running an app, screen goes whit/black when i resize the window

Comment: Could you open a bug report on kivy's github page explaining the issue?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I made a new issue on kivy's github page. The app still works when I minimize it. If I resize it first and then minimize it and restore it, the issue still persist where the window is blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused because Kivy was using Pygame. I had to brew install the SDL2 dependencies and reinstall Kivy. This fixed the problem.